Axioms of countability and quotient topology
I am trying to do the following exercise regarding axioms of countability and quotient topology:
In $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the euclidean topology) consider the equivalence relation: $(x,y) \sim (x',y') \iff x=x'$ and $y=y'$ or $y=y'=0$ (thus, the entire $x$-axis is contracted to a point). Show that the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{R}$ is not first countable.
My idea: in the quotient topology there are no open sets containing $x_0=[\mathbb{R}]=[0]$ because $\pi^{-1}(x_0)=\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$, which is not open in the euclidean topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus, there cannot exist any neighborhood of $x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{R}$, because, by definition, if such a neighborhood existed, then there would exist an open set containing $x_0$.
Is my idea correct, or completely wrong? In the second case, can you give me any hint?
Thank you for any suggestion and help!

Completely wrong, as the entire space is open by definition and contains $x_0$ (and so does any open set of the form $\mathbb{R} \times (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$). What you showed is just that ${x_0}$ is not open.

In order to prove that this space is not first-countable, you need to find a point that doesn't have a countable neighbourhood basis; as you probably guessed, that point will be $x_0$. This means that, given a countable family $(U_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of neighbourhoods of $x_0$, you should prove that there is a neighbourhood $W$ of $x_0$ that doesn't contain any of the $U_i$.


in the quotient topology there are no open sets containing $x_0=[\mathbb{R}]=[0]$

No. In fact every point in every topological space is contained in some open set, at least in the space itself.
Secondly, there are plenty open subsets containing $x_0$. For example every subset of the form $\mathbb{R}\times(-t,t)$ induces a (distinct) open neigbhbourhood of $x_0$ in the quotient space.

because $\pi^{-1}(x_0)=\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$, which is not open in the euclidean topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

This shows that $x_0$ is not open. Which is correct. And irrelevant.

Is my idea correct, or completely wrong?

Unfortunately: completely wrong.
But you are somewhat on the right track, i.e. $x_0$ is important. Assume that it has countable neighbourhood basis, i.e. there are open neighbourhoods $N_1,N_2,\ldots$ of $x_0$ such that every open subset contains at least one element of that collection.
Let $M_i=\pi^{-1}(N_i)$. Since each $M_i$ is an open neighbourhood of $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ (which is equal to $\pi^{-1}(x_0)$), then for any $x$ there is $y>0$ such that $(x,y)\in M_i$. In particular this holds for $x=i$.
In other words for any $i$ there is $y_i>0$ such that $(i,y_i)\in M_i$. With that information we construct the following neighbourhood of $x_0$:

take $U=\mathbb{R}\times (-1,-1)$
remove all $(i,y_i)$ points from it. The fact that $i$ are natural implies that what remains still is open. And the fact that $y_i>0$ implies that what remains still contains $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$.
let $V=\pi(U)$

The $V$ is an open neighbourhood of $x_0$, but no $N_i$ is contained in it.
